# Memory allocation error - malloc: cannot convert void* to structure pointer

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, malloc

I am getting this error `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'TrackedObj *'`

my TrackedObj structure looks like this :

```
typedef struct {
    IplImage* hsv;    
    IplImage* hue;    
    IplImage* mask;   
    IplImage* prob;    
    CvHistogram* hist; 
    CvRect prev_rect;  
    CvBox2D curr_box;  
} TrackedObj;
```

my code :

```
TrackedObj *obj ;
obj = malloc(sizeof *obj) ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are compiling with a C++ compiler, which does not allow conversion of `void *` to some other type without a cast.

You can either add a cast:

```
obj = static_cast<TrackedObj *>(malloc(sizeof *obj)) ;
```

Or, use `new` instead:

```
obj = new TrackedObj;
```

Make sure to use `delete` to free memory allocated with `new`.

If you rename your source file to have a `.c` extension instead of `.cpp`, your Visual C++ compiler (I am presuming this based on the `C2440` error code) should compile the source as C, and the cast of `malloc` will not be needed.

Comment: Anyone still using malloc in C++ code (other than for supporting legacy C stuff) should be terminated with extreme prejudice. +1 for `new`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Asker may be trying to code in C, but accidentally landed in C++. Hard to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

C permits implicit conversions from `void*` to other pointer types. C++ does not.

Decide which language you want to use. For C, make sure your compiler knows your code is C. For C++, either add a cast or use `new` (the latter is preferable).

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = (TrackedObj *)malloc(sizeof *obj) ;
```

Comment: Should prefer new style casts over the C style casts in C++. In C, `malloc()` result should not be cast.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = static_cast<TrackedObj *>(malloc(sizeof *obj)) ;
```

This is working for me.